# Shows dump on 404

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

In the production environment (`prod`) of this Symfony 1.4 website, a dump is shown on a 404 and on Exceptions.

http://www.10000scholen.nl/nopagehere

I want it to use the default/error404 action for a 404 and config/error/error.html.php for Exceptions. Which setting controls this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close, I think you should just need to disable the debug mode in your controller file (index.php for instance) by passing a *false* parameter :

`$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('myapp', 'prod', false);`

For your 404, you also need to edit in your *error_404_module* and *error_404_action* parameters in application *settings.yml* like [this](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/fr/04-Settings#chapter_04_sub_error_404)

Comment: That's it, great thanks :D! I didn't need to specify `error_404_module` since I've named the module default and the action `error404`.

Comment: `$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('myapp', $env, $env != 'prod');`